# Unable to run PostgreSQL as Windows service

Tags: postgresql, service

I had this in my Windows services:

```
C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/8.4/bin/pg_ctl.exe runservice -N "postgresql-8.4" -D "D:/PostgreSQL/8.4/data" -w
```

It never finishes executing. But if I did this on the dos shell:

```
C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/8.4/bin/pg_ctl.exe start -N "postgresql-8.4" -D "D:/PostgreSQL/8.4/data" -w
```

Notice that I only changed the "runservice" to "start" and it works just fine.

Any idea?

Comment: The eventlog usually contains info about the PostgreSQL start issues

Answer (score 48):

The command runservice can only be executed by the service manager

in order to fix my localhost windows 7 to start postgres as a service
i used the following command to start the data

```
 pg_ctl -D "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.1\data" start
```

Then checked the status for errors

```
 pg_ctl -D "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.1\data" status
```

if you get error 1063 , its more than likely permissions, i executed the following command

```
 cacls "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.1\data" /E /T /C /G postgres:F
```

then reran the start/status, it showed everything fine, but still service manager would not start the service

So, in Services->postgresql->options->logon i set the log on as the Local system account instead of the postgres user, and voila it worked

Comment: This worked for me too. postgresql 9.5.2. In short: in services select the service and view its properties and change the login to local system

Comment: Instead of `postgres` user, I used the `NETWORK_SERVICE` user. See here for details: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38563535/363573

Comment: Better answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36629963/how-can-i-start-postgresql-on-windows

Answer (score 11):

this happened to me because i set my data directory to be somewhere the postgres windows user account didn't have access to.

Comment: This is EXACTLY the reason why this happens! You must change the data-directory during setup to avoid this problem

Comment: For the casual reader, here is a simple method to set data directory permissions correctly: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38563535/363573.

Comment: To be noted, by default, PostgreSQL on Windows seem to use NetworkService as user.

Answer (score 8):

I had this problem in Windows after a system crash. Running the first command showed invalid data in `C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.1\data\postmaster.pid`. Deleting that file did the trick. [Reference.](http://scratching.psybermonkey.net/2009/05/postgresql-pgctl-invalid-data-in-pid.html)

Answer (score 6):

I faced the same issue after [moving manually the database data files](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Change_the_default_PGDATA_directory_on_Windows) (PG_DATA directory) without recreating all the necessary permissions.

Here is how I solved my issue:

#### 1. Check permissions on old PG_DATA directory:

```
cacls "c:\path\to\old\pgdata\dir"
```

#### 2. Check permissions on new PG_DATA directory:

```
cacls "d:\path\to\NEW\pgdata\dir"
```

#### 3. Compare outputs from 1. and 2.

*Find the differences between users and/or permissions then synchronize them.*

***Nota:*** I found it easier to use `explorer` for the synchronization step rather than using `cacls` directly from the command line.

Answer (score 4):

You need to check your logfiles and the windows eventlog for some hint of what the problem is. If there is nothing at all there, you need to break out something like Process Monitor and get a stacktrace of where it's hung.

Answer (score 4):

If you changed **pg_hba.conf** , maybe you missed somewhere in file. For example there must be CIDR after IP in that file. It must be like 192.168.1.100/32

If you forgot to put 32, then server doesnt restart.

Investigation of startup logs could be a clue. For the case problem is in the **pg_hba.conf** you could see something like this:

```
2018-11-13 00:39:34.841 PST [8284] FATAL:  could not load pg_hba.conf
2018-11-13 00:39:34.842 PST [8284] LOG:  database system is shut down
```

Answer (score 2):

I have had this issue in the past, and it was that the installer did not set up the permissions correctly for the user that the service was to run as.

Answer (score 1):

I've also ran into this problem with postgresql throwing and error after trying to initialize the database cluster. After analyzing the log files and running command line scripts for 4 hours I've got the solution to anyone running into this problem for Windows Versions.

This is not a detailed description as to why its happening. I've installed odoo 10, 11, 12 and 13 numerous times on countless client servers and windows systems and this is the first time I've ever ran into this problem. I cant say if its because I have MS VS Enterprise installed and Android Studio on this machine or what. But Below is the easy answer on how to fix it and initialize the cluster and create the database files in the data folder.

1. Open the data folder for postgresql. - For Odoo installs it will normally be "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 13.0\PostgreSQL" Unless you chose another location when installing.
2. Remove any or all files from this folder - If not you will get an error when running initdb.exe
3. Right click the data folder and open up the properties for it. Click on the Security tab and then click the advanced button on the bottom.
4. You need to change the owner of this folder to openpgsvc. Click Change and type in openpgsvc and click ok. Once done click the check box below saying that you want this change to affect containers with this container as well.
5. Then on the Permissions tab click the add button on the bottom. You need to add openpgsvc as a user and give this user full rights. Click apply and and ok to close out of all the folder properties.
6. Now you need to open cmd.exe - Once open we are going to call initdb.exe and pass some values to it as well.
7. First run chdir and change the working directory to the location of initdb.exe. For me, running odoo 13 on a windows 10 machine the location is this..

"C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 13.0\PostgreSQL\bin"

8. There is one variable that need to be passed as well to make this work here is the list. NEEDS TO BE INCLUDED IN THE CALL TO initdb.exe

Postgres Data Dir: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 13.0\PostgreSQL\data"

The End Result with the parameter would look like this for my installation:

"C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 13.0\PostgreSQL\bin\initdb.exe" -D "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 13.0\PostgreSQL\data"

9. Hit Enter and let it rip. The output of this command should look like this below.
   [Cmd.exe running initdb.exe script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9njes.png)

Answer (score 1):

```
sc create "postgresql-9.2" binPath= "\"C:/Program Files (x86)/PostgreSQL/9.2/bin/pg_ctl.exe\" runservice -N \"postgresql-9.2\" -D \"C:/Program Files (x86)/PostgreSQL/9.2/data\" -w" DisplayName= "postgresql-9.2" start= auto
```

Try this on CMD run as Administrator
(Add your parameters depend on your version)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure there is no buggy empty file `Program` at `C:\` like `C:\Program`

In this case, explorer will warn whenever you log on into Windows.

```
File Name Warning
-----------------
There is a file or folder on your computer called "C:\Program" which
could cause certain applications to not function correctly. Renaming it
to "C:\Program1" would solve this problem. Would you like to rename
it now?
```

Answer (score 1):

For **Turkish** people who installed Postgresql, I found a specific error, it may be related to localization for you too!!!

**SOLUTION**: Reinstall Postgresql with English, United States local selected.

**ISSUE**:
First of all, you need to run Postgresql manually in the terminal by this command to log what is the issue.

```
pg_ctl start -D "C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/16/data" -l logfile.txt -o "-c log_statement=all"
```

When I run this command, a file created called logfile.txt where I run this command and it's content was this;

```
2023-11-19 13:54:21.886 +03 [14736] LOG:  invalid value for parameter "lc_monetary": "Turkish_Turkey.1252"
2023-11-19 13:54:21.886 +03 [14736] LOG:  invalid value for parameter "lc_numeric": "Turkish_Turkey.1252"
2023-11-19 13:54:21.887 +03 [14736] LOG:  invalid value for parameter "lc_time": "Turkish_Turkey.1252"
2023-11-19 13:54:21.887 +03 [14736] FATAL:  configuration file "C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/16/data/postgresql.conf" contains errors
```

Answer (score 0):

Installing PostgreSQL 10 On Windows 7 (yes the clock is ticking...). I first tried the latest version 11 which completely failed to install... not a good sign for Windows users. Anyway.

Quick answer: Change the account in the Windows Services panel from Network to Local.

**Details of my case**

During installation I created/selected a data folder in the user profile folder, because obviously the folder suggested by default, within the program folder, wouldn't work, and if it worked it would be a very idea to put data here (I don't know whether it's usual to do that on Unix/Linux, but for Windows it's it's not allowed for a long time).

At the end (when populating the data cluster) I received an error:

> Failed to load SQL Modules into database Cluster

but the installation was able to complete. I found two pages about previous error, [here](https://community.ptc.com/t5/IoT-Tech-Tips/Resolving-Failed-to-load-SQL-Modules-into-database-Cluster-issue/td-p/534694) and [here](http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/install-postgresql/), but they didn't seem relevant to my case, so I just started pgAdmin and, on the left "browser", saw the server wasn't active.

I tried to start it from here (had to type the main password), but it went inactive immediately again. So I tried to use the Windows services panel to start "postgresql-x64-10", no joy. I copied the command from this panel and pasted it into a Windows console (cmd.exe) where I finally received this

> error 1063.

Searching I found this related question, and was convinced the problem was about permissions.

**Solution working for my case**

In the services panel I changed the account used to start the service from Network Service to Local System as suggested in a comment by @AlexanderRios.

Comment: 2022-Nov update: Network_Service to Local_system worked for me on Windows Server 2019 10.0.17763.3650.  COPY FROM would fail with permission errors when running under NETWORK SERVICE "log on" as for Windows Service.

Answer (score 0):

1. Stop all postgres processes
2. Go to the postgres data folder (C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.6\data)
3. Delete the postmaster.opts and postmaster.pid files
4. From the control panel, in administrative
   tools and the services console start the postgres service

Comment: postmaster.pid is not there. Removing postmaster.opts does not help.

Answer (score -5):

open pgAdmin III and then in right pane find server then just right click and connect, enter the password. after connected go to the browser and refresh ODOO. Problem solved.

See image to get better understanding

[image]