# could not connect to server: Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm using rails to develop a website but i get this error when i try to open my localhost

```
could not connect to server: Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061)
Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432? could not connect to server: Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061)
Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

How to fix it guys

Comment: are you trying to start postgres server?

Comment: I'm not sure it is the right solution but I can try, the problem is not sure how to start it on Window

Comment: are you working on windows system ? And when you get this error? while running rails s ?

Comment: Yep I'm working it on windows 8.1, I got this error when I try to run my website on localhost:3000

Answer (score 6):

In Windows, search for "services" and search for postgres in the list. Right click and select "Start".

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your postgreql server is not running.
You can try to launch it with :

On Linux :

```
 sudo service postgresql start
```

On windows : changing XX by your postgresql version run :

```
 net start postgresql-XX
```

You can also stop using postgres and specify a sqlite database in your config/database.yml file :

changing this line :

```
adapter: postgresql
```

by this line :

```
adapter: sqlite3
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, the sudo is which folder? and how specify a sqlite database in my database.yml file?

Comment: sudo is a part of the command but it is not absolutely sure that you need it.
So try :
   
    service postgresql start

If this failed with something like 'permission denied', you can try : 

    sudo service postgresql start

And if you want you can stop using postgres for your database and use sqlite : in your config/database.yml
change this line 

    adapter: postgresql
into this line :

    adapter: sqlite

Comment: I tried to write on C:/Users/name>services postgresql start, but it still can't fix the problem :(

Comment: On windows : changing XX by your postgresql version run : 

net start postgresql-XX

Comment: Sorry how do I find my postgresql? I know is psql -V but everytime i typed in CMD, it says it is not recognised as an internal or external command

Comment: This app is configured to be used with a postgresql server. Have you already launch this rails application on your computer ? If yes you should remember how do you launch postgresql : maybe with a software like pgAdmin... see this for more details : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36629963/how-to-start-postgresql-on-windows
If no maybe you have to install it

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `postgreql` this issue is due to not starting a server, so you should start the server, one way to do it is to `cd` to `postgresql` `bin` and start it with `pg_ctl`, here is an example:

```
cd "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\14\bin"
pg_ctl -D "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\14\data" start
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are running postgres in a docker image, be sure to map the container port to the host. You can do this with `docker run -p 5432:5432 <container-name>` or by adding the following to your `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
ports:
- 5342:5342
```