# Django conn= connet(dsn, connetion_factory, async=async) django.db.utils.OperationalError psycopg2

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I am working on the connection of postgresql 9.5 and Django 1.11 in wimdows 7, 
but it throws me an error

1. install python 3.4.2, add path
2. install postgresql 9.5.10, add path
3. install virtualenv version 15.1.0
4. create virtualenv myenv
5. run Scripts\myenv\activate
6. install psycopg2-2.6.2.win32-py3.4-pg9.5.3-release.exe, add folder psycopg2 in C:\proyectos\myenv\Lib\site-packages
7. install Django 1.11
8. create project Django => django-admin.py startproject redsocial
9. in the folder redsocial => django-admin.py startapp goodpeople
10. in Sublime text3

```html
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'goodpeople',
]
```

```html
DATABASES = {
  'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'goodpeople',
        'USER': 'postgresql',
        'PASSWORD': 'postgresl',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '5432',
    }
}
```

```html
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import sys

if __name__ == "__main__":
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "redsocial.settings")
    try:
        from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
    except ImportError:
        # The above import may fail for some other reason. Ensure that the
        # issue is really that Django is missing to avoid masking other
        # exceptions on Python 2.
        try:
            import django
        except ImportError:
            raise ImportError(
                "Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and "
                "available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you "
                "forget to activate a virtual environment?"
            )
        raise
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
```

11. python manage.py migrate, python manage.py test, python manage.py runserver

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/09b7C.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JJUfq.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e9GHy.png)

same result of three

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/odY71.png)

I appreciate the slightest help

Comment: is your postgresql running?

Comment: Check this post to restart Postgres service https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36629963/how-to-start-postgresql-on-windows

Comment: Yes, postgresql running

Comment: problem solved XD