# Connection from python to postgresql

Tags: python, windows, postgresql, psycopg2

I'm trying to do a connection to PostgreSQL 9.6 from Python 3.6 with Pycharm 2018.1.4 on Windows 10 with the connector psycopg2 in the version 2.7.5. I have the following code:

```
import os, psycopg2, psycopg2.extras
conexion = psycopg2.connect("dbname=Seguritec_BD user=SU host=localhost password=root port=5432")
psycopg2.OperationalError
cursor = conexion.cursor()
cursor.execute("Select * from Ejecutivos")
filas = cursor.fetchall()
```

It throws the next error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Documentos/Proyectos Pycharm/Graficos Drones/Login.py", line 3, in <module>
    conexion = psycopg2.connect("dbname=Seguritec_BD user=SU host=localhost password=root port=5432")
  File "D:\Documentos\Proyectos Python 3.5\lib\site-packages\psycopg2\__init__.py", line 130, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
psycopg2.OperationalError
```

It's an empty OperationalError, there's no description of the error.

Can you help me to understand and fix this error, please?

Comment: Thanks, i changed the language, i hope it is undestandable. Thank you.

Comment: Did you create the database Seguritec_BD on PostgreSQL? Did you start the postgres server?

Comment: Yes, it is much clearer now, thank you for translating your question :) Welcome to Stack Overflow.

Comment: Thank you a lot Andras!.
@hygorxaraujo Yes, the BD has been created, but about the postgres server
How can I make sure of that?

Comment: Which OS are you using? Windows, linux, macOS?

Comment: I'm using Windows 10

Comment: Open a terminal (cmd or powershell) and type `net status postgresql-9.6` and check the output to see if it is running. I normally use linux so I'm not sure that will work, check this other SO question https://stackoverflow.com/q/36629963/2550932.

Comment: Thank you for that, i checked that answer. I was testing, and the server is started.

Comment: What about your user (SU), does it really exist? Is the password correct? Does it have permission to access your database? I could get an error similar to yours giving the wrong credentials on connect.

Comment: Was there no message after `psycopg2.OperationalError`? Because when I tried to connect with the wrong information (user, password, database) I got something like `psycopg2.OperationalError: FATAL:  database "learning" does not exist`

Answer (score 0):

Test on Windows 10, PostgreSQL 14, Python 3.10.0, psycopg2 2.9.3

**psycopg2.OperationalError** same for wrong (**user**, **password**, **database**, **privileges**)

try to connect with [image] to see verbose message

Answer (score -1):

You have an issue so simplify it by first only using Postgresql to confirm your connection, first try psql only, substituting your values into the connection string

```
psql -U postgres -d postgres -c "SELECT *  FROM pg_user;"
```

If you need reference

```
psql --help
```