# Rails with pg "rake db:create"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, rake, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am using Windows bash for a Rails project with Postgre-sql. It's giving me the following error.

```
    **could not connect to server: No such file or directory**
    **Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?**
```

Couldn't create 'myrubyblog' database. Please check your configuration.
rake aborted!
ActiveRecord::NoDatabaseError: could not connect to server: No such file or directory

Comment: Is psql running?  I don't know much about windows but maybe try this question:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/46582472/12921091

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Verify that PostgreSQL itself is up and running on your machine.