# could not connect to server: Connection refused - pgadmin4 - postgresql

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin-4

I am getting some errors when trying to connect to a postgresql database.

**Version**: postgresql 12.3

Here are some screenshots:

[image]

This is what it looks like on the side bar. Instead of the server with a red x, it should be the postgresql elephant mascot.

[image]

Here is the error I am getting.

**What I've done to try and fix it**:

I've looked through a bunch of SO posts and stumbled across [this one](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/165290/getting-connection-refused-after-installing-postgresql-and-pg-admin-4). I checked that the `postgresql.conf` file had `listen_adresses = '*'`, which it did:

[image]

**Notes**:

I am following a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fZQI7nBu32M&t=384s) (I have gotten to that timestamp) for this, and have not yet gotten to a point where a terminal would be used. The video show's this:

[image]

where as I see what is above. I believe I may have to start the server, but I am not sure how.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution, it is definitely not the best one by any means, though.

All I did was just reinstall postgres. I am not going to mark this answer as correct, however, unless it turns out that this is, in fact, the only way to solve this problem.

Comment: You probably just needed to start service. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36629963/how-can-i-start-postgresql-on-windows
Look for Matthew Lock's answer.