# How do you set the shared_buffers parameter in PostgreSQL 14 on Windows machine?

Tags: postgresql, configuration

I have PostgreSQL 14 server running on Windows 10. I have read [here](https://www.enterprisedb.com/postgres-tutorials/comprehensive-guide-how-tune-database-parameters-and-configuration-postgresql) that the default value for the shared_buffer parameter is low and increasing it can improve performance for some jobs. However, it appears that the shared_buffer parameter cannot be increased if the server (or database?) has already been created.

So, my question is: at what point in the setup process can I increase the value of this parameter on my machine?

Comment: Changing it just requires you to restart the database (thus momentarily severing all existing connections), not recreate it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Changing `shared_buffers` does not require setting up a new database cluster.

Specifically, [the manual says](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/runtime-config-resource.html):

> This parameter can only be set at server start

In Windows terms, it means that any new values are applied at the time the Postgres Service starts.

You should be able to change the value in `postgresql.conf` (which is usually located at `C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\<version_number>\data\postgresql.conf`) and then [restart the Postgres service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36629963/how-can-i-start-postgresql-on-windows)

Since you're using v. 14, you may also opt to use `ALTER SYSTEM` instead of fiddling with `postgresql.conf`:

```
ALTER SYSTEM SET shared_buffers TO <your_value>;
```

And then restart the service

Comment: is postgresql.conf a file? Where do I find it?

Comment: yes, it's a config file -- try looking in `C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\14\data\postgresql.conf`?

Comment: How do I run this alter query if I can't access the database?  Editing postgresql.conf isn't allowing any access either.

Comment: After changing the shared_buffers to 256MB for example, running the command SHOW shared_buffers still prints out 128MB. What am I missing here ? Any ideas ?

Comment: `shared_buffers` is a parameter that is set at startup time -- it will only take effect after you restart the database (i.e., `pg_ctl -D $PGDATA restart` or `systemctl restart postgresql`, etc.).  Other possibilities include perhaps having two `postgresql.conf` files (or a `include` directive in a `postgresql.conf` file), and editing in the wrong place

Answer (score 1):

that is not what the manual of postgres says,

It only states, after increasing or decreasing  the value , you need to restart the server, because it allocates the new memory size while starting.

see [manual](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Tuning_Your_PostgreSQL_Server)