# could not connect server: connection refused(127.0.0.1)

Tags: postgresql, windows, localhost, postgresql-14

[image]I am trying to install PostgreSQL but unable to install in my windows Machine.  The following Error Throwing.

psql: could not connect server: connection refused .

installing postgreSQL

Comment: The default port of Postgres is 5432 but you are using the default port(1433) for MS SQL Server.

Answer (score 1):

1. You do not use Postgres default Port 5432 ( 1433 is for MS SQL Server) .
2. It is a daemon , so you might need to reboot/start the service /using the command line or the windows services panel

[There is a detailed post on that already](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36629963/how-can-i-start-postgresql-on-windows),

#### GUI ( Windows installer )

The GUI way if you used the Windows installer using `services.msc` applet looks like this:
[image: start postgres via services.msc]

#### You might use CLI as well

Console Example 1:

```
net start postgres_service_name
```

Console Example 2:

- locate your data folder
- locate the installation folder
- cd to install folder , start usign pg_ctl
- you might have to  use a supervisor command  line ( right-click .. run as administrator on the icon or executable of `cmd` ) for that

```
cd C:\Users\Username\Documents\postgresql-9.5.21-1-windows-x64-binaries (1)\pgsql\bin
pg_ctl -D "C:\usr\local\pgsql\data" start
```

The result on console looks like this:
[image: pg_ctl cli start]